# Why does unsafe.Sizeof return a uintptr?

Tags: go

As per the documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) `unsafe.Sizeof` returns the size of the given expression in bytes. A size of any given expression can ideally be denoted by a `uint32` or `uint64`. Then why does Golang return a `uintptr` instead? Isn't that confusing? A `uintptr` is supposed to hold a pointer to some data value but in this case it is not actually a pointer it is just a number right?

Comment: `unitptr` is an integer type that is large enough to hold any pointer. It follows that `uintptr` is large enough to hold the size of any value. A `uint32` is not large enough on some architectures.  A `uint64` is larger than needed on some architectures.

Comment: A `uintptr` is not supposed to hold a pointer, it is just an unsigned pointer-sized value (outside of unsafe use cases, you should never have an actual pointer saved as a uintptr). It's the only architecture specific unsigned numeric type.

Comment: Also because `uintptr` can be converted to `unsafe.Pointer`, it can be used for (unsafe!) pointer arithmetic, for which things like `Sizeof` might be used.

Comment: `uintptr is an integer type that is large enough to hold the bit pattern of any pointer.`
- official description of the uintptr type.

Comment: It's not *just a number*.  (Well it is really, but then so is a pointer.) It is the difference between two pointers (to the start and end of the hypothetical variable that would be created by the expression). We could have added a new `intptrdiff` type but that reeks of C and `uintptr` is a pretty good match.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers in the comments, which boil down to "because that's big enough, yet not too big".  I think, though, it might be helpful to view this from a historical perspective, with particular attention to how this all came about in the C programming language.

In very old (pre-standard) C, if you go far back enough in time, there was not even an explicit `unsigned` integer type.  The PDP-11 had:

- `char`, which was 8 bits and signed;
- `int`, which was 16 bits and signed; and
- pointers, which were 16 bits and unsigned.

That is:

```
int i;
int *u;
```

was how you made two integers, `i` being signed, and `u` being unsigned.  Setting `i` to 32767 (0x7fff) and then incrementing it gave you -32768 (0x8000), which gradually increased to -1 (0xffff) and then zero.  Setting `u` to 32767 and then incrementing it gave you 32768, which gradually increased to 65535, and then rolled over to zero.

The lack of distinction between integers and pointers meant that device drivers could read:

```
struct {
    int csr;
    int blk;
    int bar;
    int bcr;
};

0177440->bcr = count;
0177440->blk = block;
0177440->bar = addr;
0177440->csr = READ | GO;
```

which might be how one told a device to read some bytes or blocks.

(This is also why struct member names, like `st_ino` in `struct stat`, were all prefixed like this: `st_ino` just meant "some integer offset" and you could use the `st_ino` member with any pointer, or even with an ordinary variable.  The prefix meant you could `#include` multiple headers without having their struct member names collide.)

All of this turned untenable when C was made to work on 32-bit and other machines.  C grew an `unsigned` integer type, rather than pressing pointers into service as unsigned integers, and Steve Johnson's PCC compiler turned `unsigned` into a *modifier*, that could be applied to `char` and `short` as well as `int`.  A lot of experimentation occurred.  Eventually, in 1989, C was first standardized with most of the syntax and semantics that we have now (though new standards have added new types, and many functions, and so on).

Some of the early C pioneers were involved with creating Go, with particular influence from [Ken Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson).  There is a quote on the Wikipedia page that is appropriate here:

> When the three of us [Thompson, Rob Pike, and Robert Griesemer] got started, it was pure research. The three of us got together and decided that we hated C++. [laughter] ... [Returning to Go,] we started off with the idea that all three of us had to be talked into every feature in the language, so there was no extraneous garbage put into the language for any reason.

As we see from the early days of C, a pointer-as-integer is a suitable unsigned type that can not only hold any *pointer*, but, if treated as unsigned, can also hold any *object size*.  A pointer-as-integer is not directly usable as a pointer, of course, and with a GC system and concurrency, we need the language itself to have pointers.  But we also need to be able to write the runtime support *for* the language,<sup>1</sup> for which we need integer-ized pointers, which also covers all of our needs for object sizes.  So one *type*, built in to the compiler, covers all the requirements.  That is [as simple as possible, but no simpler](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/).

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "we" as if I had anything to do with it.  It's just *obvious*, once you have implemented a few runtime systems.